# C# Calling generic method for each field of class

Tags: c#, generics, system.reflection

I have a data class with several members

```
public interface IEquipmentHolder
{
    ITypedServiceProvider<IGrabberChannel> VideoChannels { get; }
    ITypedServiceProvider<IMicrophone> Microphones { get; }
    ITypedServiceProvider<ISpeaker> Speakers { get; }
    ...
}
```

and a function

```
    void visitChilds<T>(ITypedServiceProvider<T> childsList) where T : INamedComponent 
    {
      ...
    }
```

In some place of my code, I want call the function for each field of the data class. So i do:

```
visitChilds(equipment.VideoChannels);
visitChilds(equipment.Microphones);
...
```

But, probably I am going to add some new fields in the data class and don't want to forget to fix these place after that.

My question: is it possible to to call generic function for each data member of the class using reflection? if it is not, can we put compile time check for new fields in the c# code?

Comment: Yes, possible. Reflection is an option.

Comment: Also consider that this kind of problem - worrying that you will forget some code in one place when adding code in another, is cleanly solved with good unit testing. The reflection code that examines each property can be the basis of a unit test that ensures that every property is included. You would write the live code without the reflection and the test would inform you if you've missed any.

Answer (score 0):

1. How often are you going to add more fields and 'forget' to update calling code?
2. How fast are you going to find out that you've forgotten to add a call to `visitChilds()`?
3. How about `IEquipmentHolder` has only one property `ITypedServiceProvider<INamedComponent> Items { get; }`?

Reflection is slower than direct calls (maybe you should emit IL?) and the additional code may be just not worth the 'improvement', especially if it will be easy to spot that new set it not visited.

Also consider, that adding a new set of `INamedComponents` requires a breaking change to `IEquipmentHolder` interface and *all* implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) framework to generate a lambda that will call `visitChilds` for each property on the interface.

You'd need to use reflection to generate the expression, but this would be a one off hit. After that you'd have a dynamically compiled lambda you could call that would be a lot quicker.

I've done something similiar before whereby I convert an instance of an object into a `Dictionary<string,object>` where each key is the name of a property and the value is the value of the property. We generated a lambda for each type we wanted to convert, and it worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

If `ITypedServiceProvider` is covariant, i.e., declared like this,

```
ITypedServiceProvider<out T>
{
    ...
}
```

then you could have

```
IEquipmentHolder
{
    IEnumerable<ITypedServiceProvider<INamedComponent>>
        NamedComponents { get; }
}
```

then your could do

```
void VisitChildren(IEquipmentHolder equipment)
{
    foreach(var provider in equipment.NamedComponents)
    {
        provider.SomeMemberOfITypedServiceProvider();
    }
}
```